How to generate Shiboken wrappers for two C++ classes with the same name?
I'm using shiboken6, version 6.6.1, to generate Python bindings for two C++ classes.  These classes have the same name and live in different namespaces: A::Foo and B::Foo.  The wrapper classes created by Shiboken both have the same name, FooWrapper, which leads to linker errors complaining that they're both defining the same functions.
To address this, I would like the generated wrapper code to be defined in namespaces.  The Shiboken documentation says I can use generate="true" in my namespace-type directives but that isn't having any effect.
My directives look like this:
        <namespace-type name="A" generate="yes">
            <object-type name="Foo" >
        </namespace-type>

        <namespace-type name="B" generate="yes">
            <object-type name="Foo" >
        </namespace-type>

I'm hoping the generated wrapper headers will look like
namespace A
{
class FooWrapper...
};

but the namespace isn't added.  All of the definitions in the generated code are in the global namespace.
I've tried:

replacing "generate" with "generate-using" in the namespace-type directive
looking at the shiboken6 source code

I'm expecting the generated code for the wrapper classes to be defined inside of a namespace.  This is necessary to have 2 classes with the same name co-exist.

From namespace-type doc : "Note that within namespaces, the generator only supports enums (i.e., no functions or classes)."
